# DOMException: Failed to execute 'setRemoteDescription' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Failed to set remote answer sdp

Tags: node.js, reactjs, laravel, webrtc, live-streaming

i am working on live streaming using webrtc on react js but video and audio not accessible showing blank screen and getting this error on console .
[image]
I can't display the remote stream. I added the local stream to peer connection, but I can't display the remote stream because of this issue.

"DOMException: Failed to execute 'setRemoteDescription' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Failed to set remote answer sdp: Called in wrong state: ...
i am not able to connect remote stream but candidate create offer get offer worked successfully !

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your peer connection is not established. Your state of connection is new. Your offer and answers might have worked but the connection was not created ( did you exchange ice candidates ? ).

Try to make sure that connection is created between two peers and the connectionState reaches the stage 'connected'.

You can get help from chrome's option of webrtc::internals to know your connection stage. Also make sure to try from your localhost before deploying to any server/domain.

Hope this helps and please post your code so that we can answer better.